# Appropriateness of resource and news notices

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, resources

Occasionally I come across recent news or databases related to Japanese. As a community, I imagine that many of us may be interested in these topics. Is it appropriate to post brief descriptions and appropriate links here at Meta?

For example, the Online Japanese Accent Project (OJAP) just went online. [Link](http://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/ojad/).

I am not affiliated with this project, but I think it may a valuable resource for many here.

Another example: 7th century, oldest wooden fragment with names and ranks found. Relevant because these names and ranks are written in 万葉仮名 such as 白髪部伊止布 (いとふ) and 小子之母, showing the genitive -no written as 之. [Link](http://sankei.jp.msn.com/life/news/120613/art12061308420003-n1.htm).

If this kind of notice is not appropriate, please say so and this will be the last. If it is acceptable, I may occasionally post similar notices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a community blog is an option. New posts will be showcased in the "Community Bulletin" box at the right-hand side of the main site and also on meta.

Here's a [guideline for starting one](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).

Comment: I agree that a community blog is the right way to do this, but is it possible for a beta Stack Exchange site to have a community blog?

Comment: I'm sure there were some plain-looking beta icons on [community blog overview](http://stackexchange.com/blogs).. Yes, [Fitness.SE](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/) has [one](http://fitness.blogoverflow.com/) and [Christianity.SE](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [too](http://christianity.blogoverflow.com/).

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is generally how Meta is used on different Stack Exchange sites, but personally I think that it would be interesting if you did. I think we're all here to learn, and those two examples seem really interesting and even useful.

Answer (score 0):

This news is interesting, so thank you for sharing it.  However, although I am not the right person to tell you whether it is appropriate or not, I personally prefer to use the meta site for its original purpose: discuss issues about the main site.

That said, I admit that we have already been deviating from the original purpose of meta by migrating questions about external resource to the meta site (which I kind of understand but do not like very much), and that it has not caused a big problem.  So the posts like yours might be fine as well.